# Why does my app crash after creating directory in Android 9

Tags: java, android

I have a service in my app which saves files, either in `onStartCommand()` or after finishing, in `onDestroy()`. In the `onCreate()` I am checking if my app's directory and its subdirectory exist and if they don't, I create the path. However, I found out that the `exists()` method actually creates the whole path or even part of it, if it doesn't already exist. After doing that, my app actually crashes and after launching it again, it works perfect.

I've also tried surrounding the `exists()` method with a `try-catch` block but the app still crashes, without throwing any exception. This problem seems to only appear in my old device with Android 9.0, because the app doesn't have this problem on my other device, which has Android 12(API 31).
So I am wondering why is this happening and what would be a way to prevent that crash.

The code in question is:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //some other initializations...
        File dir = new File(myDirectory); /*myDirectory is the full path to my app's directory, so: 
/storage/emulated/0/directory/subdirectory */
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            try {
                if(!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    //handle failure
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
`                //handle exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I have inspected the logcat and I even tried putting some `Log.d()` message in the "handle failure" and "handle exception" sections. However, these lines aren't even reached and the only thing I am getting in the logcat is "Channel is uncoverably broken and will be disposed". From what I've read it seems this is a message associated with memory leaks and in my case it seems reasonable because the `onCreate()` method doesn't finish(at least that's what I understand) after crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving it for a while and then coming back to it, I found the problem. The problem occurs because the permission for storage is being requested and then the `bindService()` is called almost immediately, without necessarily having the storage permission granted yet. So the app tries to create the folder in the `onCreate()` method of the service(which is called when `bindService()` is called) but doesn't have the permission. The second time the app opens, the user has probably granted the storage permission(because, although the app creashes, the permission dialog remains on the screen and active), so the service is allowed to create the directory. Also this problem doesn't appear on Android 11+(maybe even Android 10 but I don't have an available device to test) because storage permission request handling changed in Android 11.

Answer (score -1):

exits: not create new folder

```
if(!dir.exists()){
  dir.mkdirs();// create your folder
}
```

//update

Comment: There is no `exits()` method. Did you mean `exists()`?

Comment: @Jamebes If you mean the `exists()` method, in my case it seems to be creating the folder/s as well because when I remove the `dir.mkdirs()` the path is still being created for some reason. That's one of my main problems/questions, apart from the crash.